# JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC in Robolectric

Tags: robolectric

I am trying to test a keystore signing in my app, but cannot pass over loading a keystore from the assets, because the error is thrown:

> java.io.IOException: error constructing MAC:
>   java.lang.SecurityException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC

here is the code

> ```
> @Test
> public void testKeyStore() {
>
>     try {
>         KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
>         InputStream inputStream = RuntimeEnvironment.application.getAssets().open(fileName);
>         keyStore.load(inputStream, password.toCharArray());
>
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     }
> }
> ```

If not with Robolectric, does anybody has an idea how to run this test?
Thanks

Comment: what are you trying to test? You actually don't need Robolectric for this java code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really don't need **Robolectric** here. Try next:

```
@Test
public void testKeyStore() throws Exception {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "src/main/assets/filename.key";
        InputStream inputStream = TimerTest.class.getResourceAsStream(path);
        keyStore.load(inputStream, "test".toCharArray());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually, this did the trick: 

String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/assets/filename.key";
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(path)
...

Comment: Updated the answer. I would suggest you to remove try/catch since it is expected that tests can throw exceptions